# String array searching in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to figure out how to search a list of names that are inputted into a string array. If the name entered is part of the original array, then the search function should return the position of the string in the array; if the string is not found, it should return -1. If -1 is returned then I want to be able to print out "not found", which doesn't seem like it would be too hard to figure out, but if the name is found, I want to be able to print out the position at which the name is found.

Here is my code, obviously I'm new to this, so I might have butchered how this is supposed to be done. The rest of my code seems to work fine, but it's this function that has me at a loss.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_NAMELENGTH 10
#define MAX_NAMES 5
void initialize(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH]);
int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int i,Number_entrys);
int main()
{
    char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH];
    int i;
    initialize(names);
    search(names,i,Number_entrys);
    search_result= search(names,i,Number_entrys);
    if (search_result==-1){
        printf("Found no names.\n");
    }
    if(search_result==0){
       printf("Name found");
    }    getch();
    return 0;
}

void initialize(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH])
{
    int i, Number_entrys;

    printf("How many names would you like to enter to the list?\n");
    scanf("%d",&Number_entrys);

    if(Number_entrys>MAX_NAMES){
               printf("Please choose a smaller entry\n");
    }else{
        for (i=0; i<Number_entrys;i++){
            scanf("%s",names[i]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<Number_entrys;i++){

        printf("%s\n",names[i]); 
    }
}

int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int i)
{
    int j, idx;
    char name[MAX_NAMELENGTH];
    printf("Now enter a name in which you would like to search the list for:");
    scanf("%s", name);

    for(x = 0; x < Number_entrys; x++) {
        if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 ){
            /* match, x is the index */
            return x;
        }else{
            return -1;   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

The purpose of search is to ask the user to enter a single name to be searched for. So why is

```
 char new_name[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH];
```

You need only a single array

```
 char new_name[MAX_NAMELENGTH];
```

Then you have a loop you just go round once, so you don't need a loop

```
 scanf("%s",new_name);
```

would be enough. This feels like you have copied the code you used to fill your array of names, but haven't really understood its essence.

Another problem is that you have no control on how long a name the user might enter. What would happen if the user typed a very long name? You'd over-fill the array and your program will probably crash and burn. Read [this article](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/String-overflows-with-scanf.html) to learn about how to control this.

To be really pedantic you should also check the return code from scanf, you are expecting to read one item so the return value should be 1, anything else would be an error.

Then you are trying to use strstr(), to look through an array of char arrays. The strstr [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html) says that its purpose is to search for a substring within a string rather than search through an array of strings.

So instead just search the array by hand

```
/* what is i? the number of items used in the array? */
for(x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 ){
        /* match, x is the index */
        return x;
    }
}
/* here with no match */
return -1;
```

In your main

int search_result;

```
search_result = search( /* etc */ );

if ( search_result == -1 ) {
     /* print "not found" here */
} else {
     /* print something else */
}
```

Comment: Wow, I actually feel pretty dumb for those array mistakes, because clearly what I had doesn't make sense, thank you for catching that. Now in order to print either the position of the name found or a statement letting the user know that the name wasn't found in the main(), would I use an IF statement in the main() and call this function? Or would that not work ?

Comment: weird, if the name entered is not part of the list it crashes.

Comment: it wont acknowledge if the entry was not part of the list, and if it was part of the list I can't get it to print the position of the name.If anything it should at least acknowledge the name not being in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You means like this:

```
int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH], int i)
{
     int j, idx;
     char name[MAX_NAMELENGTH];
     printf("Now enter a name in which you would like to search the list for:");
     scanf("%s", name);

     idx = -1;
     for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
         if(strstr(names[i], name) != NULL){
             idx = j;break;
         }
     }
     return idx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(8) ...
Maybe we'll turn it all around
'Cause it's not too late
It's never too late!! (8)
:) !

---

Sorry about the song ^_^... oh Well, I was having fun with this question for a couples of minutes, I hope this code help you out a little more, with regards:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* return array of indexs */

int*
search(const char *list, size_t slen, const char **arr_names, size_t arrlen)
{
    int *arr_idx;
    int j,i,idx;

    i=idx=0;

    arr_idx = malloc(sizeof(int)*arrlen+1);

    if(!arr_idx)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for(i=0; i<slen; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<arrlen ; j++) {
            if(!strncmp(&list[i], &arr_names[j][0], strlen(arr_names[j]))) {
                arr_idx[idx] = j;
                idx++;
            }
        }
    }

    arr_idx[idx] = -1; /* -1 terminated array */
    if(!idx) {
        free(arr_idx);
        return NULL; /* found no names */
    }

   return arr_idx;
}
/* I'm a sick [something], nul terminated strings :P */
const char *string   = "My favorite artists: ATB, Nujabes and Bonobo also Aphex Twins is nice, along with Trapt and Breaking Benjamin.\0";
const char *names[] = {"ATB\0", "Scifer\0", "Aphex\0", "Bonobo\0", "Nujabes\0", "Tipper\0"};
#define N_NAMES 6

int
main(void)
{
    int i;
    int *array;

    array = search(string, strlen(&string[0]), names, N_NAMES);

    if(!array) {
        puts("Found no names.\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    printf("Names found: ");
    for(i=0; array[i]!=-1; i++)
        printf("%s,", names[array[i]]);

    printf("\b \n");
    free(array);  /* important */
    /* system("pause"); */   /* NOTE: decomment this if you're on windows */
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**ran some tests:**
 
`~$ ./program`

**output**
`Names found: ATB,Nujabes,Bonobo,Aphex`

Comment: haha I appreciate the in depth response and the light heartedness. Unfortunately you went into a little more depth then I've come to understand yet lol. I'm trying to run your code, and break it down so I can learn from it, but I'm getting an error at `arr_idx = malloc(sizeof(int)*arrlen+1);` that says "invalid conversion from void to int". Any thoughts?

Comment: oh, nice :) ... mmm any chance you're using a C++ compiler? try with `arr_idx = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*arrlen+1);` to see what happens.

Comment: Made the adjustment and it fixed the error, but the program flashes on the screen just long enough for me to tell something happened and then disappears lol. I am using a C++ compiler, which could be part of the issue. Tried using `getch()` to force it to hang,  but it didn't work. :(

Comment: @DatDudeJC, I see your problem, you should then put this line `system("pause");` just after the `free(array);` at the end of `main()` function, that should fix the problem. DatDudeJC, you are dealing with another issue, that program needs an argument, instead I'll edit the code so you can call it without arguments just remember to descomment the line `system("pause");` I did it to protect non-windows users from getting an error.

Comment: sweet, got it to work. I'm going to hold onto this code so I can try and learn some stuff that I haven't come across yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I got everything running like I need it to on my program, but my only hang up is how to print the position of the name in which is found in the list. I know I need to print the index, but I can't seem to get it to work. You got a suggestion on how I return the index of X to the main and then print it?

Comment: According to this answer, for performance issues you want to rewrite the `search()` function, but in this case is better if you use `strstr()` instead. For example, suppose you're returning from `search()`, in that moment you have an array of indexes, you then could use it like this: `sptr = strstr(string, array[0])` and with a little of math you just: `index = sptr - string` there it is. In this very example `index` is equals to `21` and `sptr` points to the beginning of the `"ATB"` substring.